# Highlight variables in echo

Tags: bash, colors

Given the following:

```
text="The quick $color fox jumps over the $adjective dog"
```

How can I echo `$text` with `$color` and `$adjective` values being colored in bash, but not changing the variable?

Example:

```
$ echo -e --highlight-variables $text
The quick \e[00;31mbrown\e[00m fox jumps over the \e[00;31mlazy\e[00m dog
```

(except with the actual colors)

But then:

```
$ echo -e $text
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

would have no color changes.

I want to be able to output the text with `less` so the user can review it in the console, but then write the variables to a file, but the file should not have the color info in it. The actual code I'm executing looks something like:

```
echo -e $text | less
echo "Is this acceptable?"
read accept
if [ "$accept" == "y" ]
  then
  echo -e $text > output.txt
fi
```

If I wrap the variables in color, the escaped text gets put in the file.

Comment: You can't do it precisely like that. There's no possible way to know where the expansions took place. You'll have to use an array and piece together the escape codes (should be generated from tput) and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove ansi sequences before you print.

```
nocolor()
{
perl -pe "s/\e\[\d+(?>(;\d+)*)m//g;"
}

echo -e $text | less
echo "Is this acceptable?"
read accept
if [ "$accept" == "y" ]
  then
  echo -e $text | nocolor > output.txt
fi
```